# parsing - Preg match text in php between wordpress shortcodes

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

Hello I would like to use preg_match in PHP to parse the nested Wordpress shortcodes out of the following from a string. but my preg doesn't work.

```
$str = '[according-wr]
            [according]
                [icon]eonrolf[/icon]
                [title]Title[/title]
                [src]http://dcijnionc.com/rfeojf[/src]
                [text]dsionodsovndsl lkdsnikndsln slodsvndx  sdvopndsponvdxs ndsxpn pd.[/text]
            [/according]
        [/according-wr]';

preg_match_all('/\[according-wr\](.*?)\[\/according-wr\]/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

it return an empty array!

Comment: @Uchiha Yes I know and I changed codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot `.` is not matching new-line characters by default, you need the `s` modifier for that:

```
$preg = preg_match_all('/\[according-wr\](.*?)\[\/according-wr\]/s', $str, $matches);
                                                                 ^ here
```

Also see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more information about the `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier.

A [working example](https://regex101.com/r/lV5fE2/1).